# What do -​- (two dashes) mean in Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

If you enter the command line `cargo test --help`, the following message is shown:

> The test filtering argument TESTNAME and all the arguments following the
>   two dashes (`--`) are passed to the test binaries and thus to libtest
>   (rustc's built in unit-test and micro-benchmarking framework). If you're
>   passing arguments to both Cargo and the binary, the ones after `--` go to the
>   binary, the ones before go to Cargo. For details about libtest's arguments see
>   the output of `cargo test -- --help`.

I do not understand the principle idea of that. Is `libtest` not included in `cargo test` execution? What's the difference between both? Can someone explain how it works with examples and the main idea of passing arguments using two dashes?

Comment: It's a UNIX convention: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187548/5217

Comment: `cargo test` compiles the tests and runs the test binaries. The arguments to Cargo control how to compile and run the binaries, while the arguments after `--` are simply passed through to the binaries.